# H2: Read Comment on Column?

Tags: ubuntu, h2, squirrel-sql

Just started using the H2 database.   Have found the COMMENT command but as I have already set the comment through LibreOffice, is there any way to return it?
This is a sense check as I can set and see column comments  in H2 via Squirrel, but Squirrel does not show comments set via Libre.

thanks

paul

Answer (score 2):

Comment are usually used as a remark on the source code. You will get them back when running the [`SCRIPT`](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#script) statement.

But you can also retrieve them from the database meta data, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  NAME VARCHAR(255) COMMENT 'Hello World');

(SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, REMARKS 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE REMARKS <> '')
UNION ALL
(SELECT TABLE_NAME, '', REMARKS 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE REMARKS <> '')
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME;
```

Comment: The purpose of the post is to try to determine if I have found a bug in Squirrel - running the above returns ~no~ columns with comments, although I know there should be at least one created from Squirrel and several created from LibreOffice.  Are the Libre comments just stored in the Base file as a metadata overlay, do you know?.

Comment: I'm sorry, this I don't know. You could check using the `SCRIPT` command if there are comments on the column (this I would do first I guess).